# Get image using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this class:

```
<a class = photo_wrap href = "https//:somelink" style="/* width:100px; */background-image:url("urlImage") </a>
```

How can I get only urlImage from here? Tried this, but it gives width as well.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
for (Element element: document.select(".photo_wrap")) {
            String style = element.attr("style");
            System.out.println(style);
        }
```

Here is what I would like to get:

```
background-image:url("urlImage")
```

Comment: are you trying to get image url (urlImage in this case)?

Comment: Yes, urlImage..

Comment: please add sample data and expected output in your question description

Comment: I don't think jsoup supports parsing css...

Comment: added, I think everything quite clear

Comment: @dan1st what can I use then?

Comment: You can use simple string manipulation functions - find the location of the double quoutes and get all the substring between these locations. You can also use regex, but this is a simple pattern, so string functions will do.

Comment: @TDG Which String function can I use here? No idea

Comment: Try `String.indexOf()`.

Comment: String.indexOf() will give me the position, but i need to get url itself

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to use jsoup to grab only specific parts of the contents of `style` attribute. You can user regular expression to extract exactly what you want.

```
// import java.util.regex.Matcher;
// import java.util.regex.Pattern;

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("background-image:url\\(([^)]*)\\)");

for (Element element : doc.select(".photo_wrap")) {
    String style = element.attr("style");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(style);
    if (m.find()) {
        String urlImage = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(urlImage);
    }
}
```